# kotlin reflection get list of fields

Tags: reflection, jvm, kotlin

is there an equivalent for the java reflection `foo.getClass().getFields()` in Kotlin? I could only find that I can access a field when I know it's name, but I would like to handle fields in a generic way.

Comment: AFAIK it's under development. Feel free to star or vote to related issue(https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6570) to get updates.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I can't find the button to "accept" you answer..

Comment: This is possible, the issue mentioned above is fixed, and sample code is in an answer below.

Answer (score 24):

Did you want fields as-in "backing field" or fields as in "properties"  ... Kotlin really only has properties.  You can get these for some class using:

```
MyTest::class.memberProperties

// or 

MyTest::class.declaredMemberProperties
```

And from a Java `Class<T>`, use the `kotlin` extension property to get the Kotlin `KClass<T>` from which you can proceed:

```
someClassOfMine.javaClass.kotlin.memberProperties
```

This requires the `kotlin-reflect` dependency as well to be added to your build and classpath.  You'll find many other useful things on `KClass`

For the secret backing fields behind a property, use Java reflection at your own risk.

Answer (score 5):

Very easy now with Kotlin v1.1, You can use the following method to get the fields in kotlin

```
val fields = MyClass.javaClass.kotlin.members
```

Where MyClass is the class of your choice.

In order to use this you need to have kotlin-reflect included in your gradle build file as below

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```

Additionally, it is also possible to get the fields from the javaClass directly if you need java fields (useful in some cases as these cover a slightly different scope)

```
val fields = MyClass.javaClass.declaredFields
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in Kotlin, but there is a dirty unreliable way to do this in java. You can use java reflection. Like this:

```
public class TestClass {

    trait EmptyTrait
    class EmptyClass

    public var anotherVar:Int? = null
    public val contant:Float = 10f
    private var emptyTrait:EmptyTrait? = null
    val emptyClass:EmptyClass = EmptyClass()

    public fun setVal(fieldName: String, value: Int) {
        javaClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName).set(this, value);
    }

    public fun getFieldNames(): String {
        return javaClass.getDeclaredFields().map{it.getName()}.join(", ")
    }    
}
```

Let's test it:

```
val t = TestClass()
Log.v("MainActivity", "Fields: " + t.getFieldNames())
Log.v("MainActivity", "anotherVar: " + t.anotherVar)
t.setVal("anotherVar", 10)
Log.v("MainActivity", "anotherVar: " + t.anotherVar)
```

Results:

```
Fields: anotherVar, emptyClass, emptyTrait, contant, $kotlinClass
anotherVar: null
anotherVar: 10
```

it works )

Comment: That is not what I need, I want to iterate over the fields of classes (which may have any number of fields with names that I don't know), hence the question for a "list" (of any kind)..

Comment: there is getFields method, a moment )

Comment: Kotlin reflection can do this much more easily, what the question is asking for...

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer

In you build.gradle (app) file

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version")
```

And then

```
val fields = YourClass::class.declaredMemberProperties
for (i in fields){
    Log.e("Fields ===", i.name)
}
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: I was able to get the field names, but how to get field values?

Answer (score 2):

There is a method in *Kotlin* that works without  having to add a new dependency in a project:

Suppose a custom class called `Mine`

```
class Mine(var prop:String) {
    fun myMethod():Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

A new user function called `isMethod`

```
fun isMethod(t:Any, s:String):Boolean {
try  {
    t.javaClass.getMethod(s)   // or t::class.java.getMethod(s)
    return true
  } catch(e:Exception)  {
    return false
  }    
}
```

After one declares an `Mine` instance and test it.

```
fun main() {
  var m = Mine("Paulo")  
  println(isMethod(m, "myMethod"))  // it prints true
  println(isMethod(m, "otherMethod"))  // it prints false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the properties in the order they are declared using `Kotlin-reflect`:
`MyClass::class.primaryConstructor.parameters`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `memberProperties`.

Example:

```kotlin
class Color {
    val name: String
    val red: Int
    val green: Int
    val blue: Int
}

// ...

Color::class.memberProperties.size // returns 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your example with a `foo` variable you may get its backing fields through:

```kotlin
val fields: List<Field?> = foo::class.memberProperties.map { it.javaField }
```

Answer (score -1):

like this:

```
  User::class.memberProperties.forEach { member ->
        log.i("${member.name} -> ${member.get(this)}")
    }
```

It works very well

Comment: kotlin memberProperties are not the same as java fields.

especially when used with annotations there are subtle differences. Just for iterating this might work, but annotations mighty be empty (if they don't have the right use-site target)