# Loop within data class declaration in Kotlin?

Tags: android, loops, class, kotlin, android-room

Apologies, I am fairly new to Kotlin!

What I have:

```
@entity(tableName = "main_table")
data class Table(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var tableId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "column_name") val columnName: String?,

    ...

)
```

What I would like:

```
val columnList = listOf(...list of strings...)

@entity(tableName = "main_table")
data class Table(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var tableId: Int,
    
    for (column in columnList)
        @ColumnInfo(name = column+"_name") val column+Name: String?,

    ...

)
```

Motivation: that list will be re-used in other parts of the code, as such, it would be great if it only existed within the code once.

Two unknowns here for me, can that loop be done somehow? And can concatenation be done during the variable declaration?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: And what would the list of columns be used for in other parts of the app?

Comment: There is no way to do what you're suggesting in pure Kotlin. Parameter names cannot be generated by code at compile time unless you create some sort of annotation processor that generates code for you using some sort of script that you analyze as a String annotation parameter. That's how stuff like `@Query` work

Comment: @DavidKroukamp for example, outputting the list to screen like in autocomplete edit text boxes.

Comment: Yeah I don't think that makes sense, your app would usually have user friendly column names and not the exact column name unless your app is some sort of database query app. Otherwise if you do need this you would simply use reflection to enumerate all properties in the class and add them to a list https://stackoverflow.com/q/28391889/1133011

Comment: @DavidKroukamp since the column names follow a pattern, I could quite easily manipulate the string to display the format I require (i.e. in a user friendly manner). Since I would also like the user to be able to input a database object, I will need an efficient method to create an edit textbox for each column and as such will need the list. Of course, this can all very easily be done if I just write the names manually, but that sort of defeats the purpose of a high level programming language? I'll have a look at the answer you posted, it might just be what I want. Thank you.