# Kotlin get all property value of data class

Tags: kotlin, data-class

Is there a syntactic sugar in Kotlin to iterate on each field/property value of a data class?

Sample:

```
data class User(
    var firstName: String = DEFAULT_VALUE_STRING,
    var middleName: String = DEFAULT_VALUE_STRING,
    var lastName: String = DEFAULT_VALUE_STRING
)

val user = User()
```

Then check if any of the property's value is empty, considering all of it is String data type with something like this

```
if (user.properties.any{ it.isBlank() }) {

   // TODO ...

}
```

Comment: You can use reflection, but it isn't very performant. Don't be lazy, just write a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin reflection get list of fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391889/kotlin-reflection-get-list-of-fields)

Comment: P.s. for many people, middle name will always be empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the closest you'll get is checking all the values of all the generated `componentX()` functions (since they're only created for the constructor parameter properties, the "data" in a data class) but yeah that involves reflection.

If I were you, I'd create an interface with a `properties` property and make all your data classes implement that - something like this:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty0

interface HasStringProperties {
    val properties: List<KProperty0<String>>
}

data class User(
    var firstName: String = "",
    var middleName: String = "",
    var lastName: String = ""
) : HasStringProperties {
   override val properties = listOf(::firstName, ::middleName, ::lastName)
}

fun main() {
    val user = User("Funny", "", "Name")
    println(user.properties.any {it.get().isBlank()})
}
```

So no, it's not automatic - but specifying which properties you want to include is simple, and **required** if you're going to access it on a particular class, so there's an element of safety there.

Also, because you're explicitly specifying *`String`* properties, there's type safety included as well. Your example code is implicitly assuming all properties on your data classes will be `String`s (or at least, they're a type with an `isBlank()` function) which isn't necessarily going to be true. You'd have to write type-checking into your reflection code - if you say "I don't need to, the classes will only have String parameters" then maybe that's true, until it isn't. And then the reflection code has to be written just because you want to add a single *age* field or whatever.

---

You don't actually have to use property references in Kotlin either, you could just grab the current values:

```
interface HasStringProperties {
    val properties: List<String>
}

data class User(
    var firstName: String = "",
    var middleName: String = "",
    var lastName: String = ""
) : HasStringProperties {
   // getter function creating a new list of current values every time it's accessed
   override val properties get() = listOf(firstName, middleName, lastName)
}

fun main() {
    val user = User("Funny", "", "Name")
    println(user.properties.any {it.isBlank()})
}
```

It depends whether you want to be able to reference the actual properties on the class itself, or delegate to a getter to fetch the current values.

And of course you could use generics if you want, list all the properties and use `filterIsInstance<String>` to pull all the strings. And you could put a function in the interface to handle a generic *isEmpty* check for different types. Put all the "check these properties aren't 'empty'" code in one place, so callers don't need to concern themselves with working that out and what it means for each property

Comment: Very good answer. Just a little typo in the second example: extra `::` in `listOf(firstName, ::middleName, ::lastName)`. It should be `listOf(firstName, middleName, lastName)`

Comment: @ocos oh yeah, thanks! Looks like I got distracted editing the original :3

Comment: Thanks, maybe I will just go for the second one which is way more simple and performant.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS they're both about as performant as each other - using function references just creates a Java `Function` object under the hood, it's not actual reflection (even though `KFunction0` is part of the `reflect` package - you only need to import it if you're explicitly using the `KFunction0` type somewhere, like I needed to do for the interface). If you don't *need* references then there's no reason to use them - keep it simple! But don't be afraid to use them, there's a tiny bit more memory overhead but it's basically irrelevant in most cases. It's not the same impact as reflection